# Postgres: Dynamic creation of a temporat table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create a report based on a few variables, one of them being months in a year. I would like to create a temporary table containing only the desired periods. Here's what I came up with:

The parts I'm having trouble with are placed between << and >>

```
DO $$
DECLARE myPeriodFrom INTEGER := 7;
DECLARE myPeriodTo INTEGER := 9;
DECLARE myColumn VARCHAR(255) := 'Period';
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTable;
    CREATE TABLE tmp_table (tmpId INT, tmpDesc varchar(255));
    FOR i IN myPeriodFrom..myPeriodTo LOOP
        -- Create dynamic column name and fill with data
        << code here >> -- myColumn := (myColumn || CAST(i AS VARCHAR)); 
        ALTER TABLE tmpTable ADD COLUMN << myColumn >> INT;
        INSERT INTO tmpTable (myId, myColumn)
            SELECT "Id", "YearAdded" FROM "Item" WHERE "Item"."MonthAdded" = i;
    END LOOP;

END $$;
SELECT * FROM tmpTable
```

Comment: Why would you use a temporary table when `generate_series()` probably does what you want?

Comment: Not quite, `generate_series()` doesn't quite do the trick. Still need the columns. When this works other calculations have to take place within the `SELECT`. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

With a little regret I'm afraid to conclude that what I want is not possible. There is no real workable solution to dynamicly create columns.
Second, the application I'm using the query in turns out not to support queries with dynamic output. For these reasons I had to rethink my whole approach.

For those who read it and gave a suggestion, thanks.